# ARC Autoreleased with no pool in place

Tags: iphone, xcode, automatic-ref-counting

I am using ARC in my code and I am getting the error

```
Object 0x781b8e0 of class __NSCFString autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking - break on objc_autoreleaseNoPool() to debug
```

The line it breaks on is

```
  return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([HomePageAppDelegate class]));
```

Since I am using ARC I cannot put an `NSAutoReleasePool` around it like I usually would. What can I use in order to fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this on the line where it showing the `warning`

```
@autoreleasepool{
}
```

Comment: -1 simply because you didn't elaborate on what this does. Considering the fact that the OP doesn't appear to be a master at the language, it's always good to cite some facts or references about the code you posted.

Comment: There was nothing to state much in that question the answer i said simple saying to keep the statement inside of these line. If you dont understand doesn't mean everyone dont understand. The answer is correct and it was self explanatory. Dont miss guide every one. Focus on your answers not on others until it was wrong

Comment: @Sumanth - He's not at all misguiding anyone. We do prefer answers that aren't just code dumps, but which explain why you're doing something. In this case, his is currently the better answer because it provides context for why you'd want to do this.

Answer (score 6):

You use the `@autoreleasepool` construct:

```
@autoreleasepool {
    // main code here
}
```

This creates a `NSAutoReleasePool` with the same scope as the brackets, and it can also be used in MRC code as well. It has the advantages of being cleaned up when exceptions occur, and can easily be used to dispatch threads safely.

To read more, visit this article on [Transitioning to ARC Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011226-CH1-SW8)

Answer (score 0):

Create a new test app with ARC enabled.  Look at the code in "main.m" to see what Apple recommends.

Comment: Seems like a bit of a waste considering that two answers showed that it isn't that complex.

Comment: When there's a way for someone to find out the answer to something by themselves, I'd rather point them in that direction than simply dump an obvious line of code on them.  If that doesn't fit the spoon-feeding philosophy of some SO people, tough.  :-)

Comment: The thing about this is that it doesn't help future visitors. It is completely in Apple's power to change their template projects to do something other than create an autorelease pool at launch, and you can't rely on this never changing.

Comment: It doesn't need to be never changing.  If they (Apple) someday decide the annotation should be spelled differently, the direct advice in this thread will be wrong for new visitors but the method of discovering what would work would still be valid.