# Calling Objective C from C

Tags: objective-c, c, xcode, macos

I have a callback function in C which looks like this:

```
 void cfunc(char* labelUpdateText)
```

This callback function is supposed to update the text of a label in my app's UI by changing the label's current text to whatever labelUpdateText is.

So in cfunc I'm trying to call this Objective C function:

```
-(void)updateLabel:(char*) text
{
    [_labelProp setStringValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [NSString stringWithUTF8String:text]]];
}
```

However, I can't call the objective C function from my C function.

I tried like this:

```
updateLabel:labelUpdateText
```

But when I build the code, I get the warning 'Expression result unused'

And the 'updateLabel:labelUpdateText' doesn't execute.

What am I doing wrong?

PS: I am new to Objective C!

Comment: Have you tried compiling it as Objective-C? Alternatively, you could expose Objective-C as a web service and hit that from your C code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to provide the callback function with a pointer to the view containing the label and some means of updating it.  All callback functions should have a *context pointer* of some sort which can hold information allowing them to perform context-specific actions.  If you cannot change the callback function semantics then you are stuck I'm afraid, however if you can, do it something like this:

```
void cfunc(const char *labelUpdateText, void *contextInfo) {
    YourView *view = (YourView *)contextInfo;
    [view updateLabelWithText:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:labelUpdateText]];
}
```

You will need to provide the `updateLabelWithText` method in `YourView` and if you are using ARC there will be some bridging to do as well during the casting of `contextInfo` (the compiler will help you there though).

Comment: I saved the pointer to the label in a global variable which the callback then uses. Seems to work fine :-) Thank you for the feedback!

Comment: The only problem I'm having now is when I update the label, I get this message in the console: "Object ##### of class #### autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking ...." . My app is using ARC. UPDATE: Found the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227237/arc-autoreleased-with-no-pool-in-place

Answer (score 0):

Why not just make a wrapper C function in the Objective C class that calls the ObjC syntax and call the C function from your C program that needs to make the callback.